# Whistle detection with devices having ICS Android?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audio-recording, voice-recognition

I am using [musicg](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/) library for Whistle Detection in my app.

So far, the library works great when I test it on devices having Froyo, GingerBread or even JellyBean, but when testing on ICS it does not detect the whistles properly.

In the library for Whistle detection, it has a class named, ***WhistleApi.java*** having boundary values for frequency, intensity, standard deviation etc:

```
protected void init(){
    // settings for detecting a whistle
    minFrequency = 600.0f;
    maxFrequency = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    minIntensity = 100.0f;
    maxIntensity = 100000.0f;

    minStandardDeviation = 0.1f;
    maxStandardDeviation = 1.0f;

    highPass = 100;
    lowPass = 10000;

    minNumZeroCross = 50;
    maxNumZeroCross = 200;

    numRobust = 10;
}
```

So far, I know by analyzing logs that the whistle is not being recognized in the **isPassedStandardDeviation(double[][] spectrogramData)** of the class [***DetectionApi.java***](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/source/browse/src/com/musicg/api/DetectionApi.java).

The AudioRecord is being initialized like this:

```
private int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private int sampleRate = 44100;
private int frameByteSize = 2048;

int sampleRate = AudioTrack.getNativeOutputSampleRate(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
int recBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding); // need to be larger than size of a frame
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleRate, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, recBufSize);
```

I have tried different workarounds by changing the boundary value in ***WhistleApi.java*** class to no results. Can anyone guide me, where am I overlooking or where can I find the mistake in the library ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I faces similar problem. For me whistleDemo was detecting whistle on micromax funbook pro tablet with ICS but was not detecting whistle in micromax A110 phone with ICS.

In whistleApi I changed minNumZeroCross from 50 to 20 and it resolved the problem.

Comment: thanks this really helped me. do you know how to change the accuracy.  i mean how can i whistle for about 3 seconds and only detect only one whistle :)